# AMP setState not working properly in server

Tags: tabs, amp-html, setstate

I am trying to implement AMP Tab Panel with AMP Selector. 
Everything working fine in localhost. 
But it does not work in server properly. That means it work sometimes but not all the time in server.

I tried adding #development=1 to url and AMP.printState() in console. it showing that state are changing, but tab are not changing.

(sorry for my bad english)

```
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({selectedTab: 'a'})" >Internet</button>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({selectedTab: 'b'})" >Voice</button>

<amp-selector on="select:AMP.setState({selectedTab: event.targetOption})" [selected]="selectedTab" role="tablist" layout="container" class="ampTabContainer">
  <div role="tab" class="tabButton" selected option="a" hidden>Internet</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">Internet content</div>
  <div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="b" hidden>Voice</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">Voice content</div>
</amp-selector>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the page where this is happening?

Comment: https://ergo-ventures.com/amp/
There is a button "Add Another", at the right side of banner. clicking this button will show another input field. 
It works fine in first load, after refreshing the page it sometimes works and sometimes not. @JamesIves